# Python 3 pseudocode Do-While loop

Tags: python, pseudocode

I need to design a  Do-While loop that asks the user to enter two numbers. The numbers should be added and the sum displayed. The loop should ask the user whether he or she wishes to perform the operation again. If so, the loop should repeat; other-wise it should terminate.

This needs to be done in Python pseudocode, which makes absolutely no sense to me because why not use Python in the first place?

Thanks

Comment: Python doesn't have a do-while loop.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: This is from a Python-oriented text book. The book is "Starting Out with Programming Logic and Design.

Comment: More specifically a "do-while" loop in Python 3 is a type of a condition-controlled loop. Perhaps you were confused by how the question was worded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
While True
    ask user for input1
    ask user for input2
    display input1 + input2
    ask user if they want to go again
    if no then exit
```

Comment: pseudo code at it best :D